# How to add a new page to a website in visual studio

Tags: c#, vs-web-site-project

I am new to coding and visual studio and I would like to add pages (about us, products,...) to my website that already has a home page. I am using visual Studio and C#

What do I have to do to create a new page?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide detail of your problem and follow these guidelines. It is impossible to help with no detail of your project https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Open your folder "Views", right mouse click on folder "Home" and then look at the picture I added. My visual studio is in German so I can't say exactly what's next, but this should work. 
[image: picture]

Comment: Is there a step by step video on how to do it?